# Suggestion for Grid for MFC SDI application

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, grid

Currently we are using Xtreme Toolkit Pro Grid control with virtualization support for our application to show the contents in Grid. Is there any other better software which can be easily used as Grid without much changes in the application.

Also can I able to achieve the full use of Grid in CMFCPropertyGridCtrl which is present in MFC feature pack.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you call 'better'. What do you need it to do what your current solution doesn't.

Answer to your second question is 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.bcgsoft.com their grid is much better:
http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour194.htm

we're using it for a long time.